# Getting all active constraints of an LP from Cplex

Tags: cplex, cplex-python-api

I was wondering if it is possible to get the active constraints of a linear program from the Python API of Cplex? Or do I have to go through the constraints one by one and check if they bind with equality for the current solution?

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the basis status of the rows. **Non-basic** means binding.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to find the method `cplex.solution.basis.get_basis()`.  Should I use `cplex.solution.basis.get_basis()[1]`, and those that are 1 correspond to active constraints?

Comment: I agree that nonbasic implies binding, but what about slack variables that are basic but equal to zero?

Comment: @prubin. Then use my favorite approach: do some hand-waving. My number two solution: define binding as being non-basic. Number three: assume non-degeneracy. Last resort: do more checking (basic rows only).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I vote for your last resort. Re your favorite approach, hand-waving is legally reserved for academics. (I believe the EU has a law to that effect; in the US, it's just accepted practice.)

Comment: @prubin I am usually way sloppier. I often just look at the dual.

Comment: And I am usually way lazlier: I just query the value of the LHS of each constraint and see if it is within tolerance of the RHS, thus optimizing coder time at the possible expense of run time.